# Parameter Keys Have Square Brackets Alamofire iOS

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How can I prevent the Alamofire from encoding (replacing my square brackets with `%5B` and `%5D`)?

I saw someone's comment about this a while ago but I couldn't find the link to the question anymore. My parameter looks like this:

```
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "xx[firebase_id]" : currentUserId,
        "xx[lat]"         : latitude,
        "xx[lng]"         : longitude,
        "xx[fcm_key]"     : fcmKey
    ]
```

I've had a quite similar problem before when my parameter was a collection and the solution was just remove the brackets, like so:

from this: `["some_array_param[]" : someCollection]`

to this `["some_array_param" : someCollection]`

So going back to my simple question, should I just talk to my backend developer about this? Or is there a way to fix this on my end (without putting the parameters manually in the url)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I accomplished it via encoding the parameters:

```
// Remove square brackets for POST request
let parameterEncoding = ParameterEncoding.Custom { requestConvertible, parameters in
    let (mutableRequest, error) = ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(requestConvertible, parameters: parameters)
    let httpBody = NSString(data: mutableRequest.HTTPBody!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    mutableRequest.HTTPBody = httpBody.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%5B%5D=", withString: "=").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return (mutableRequest, error)
}
```

Then add the encoding to your post:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://example.com", parameters: ["foo": ["bar1", "bar2"]], encoding: parameterEncoding)
```

Comment: Awesome. Saw this answer somewhere but was kinda skeptical to try it out. Will try it out now. :D I'll select this as an answer if this works for me.

Comment: Your code is not updated, try to update it like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40546670/3231194, however, when you posted this, you gave me an idea to try it out, so long story short, I have fixed what I needed to fix. Thanks to you.